# SQLGrammerException: could not get ResultSet on em.persist()

Tags: jpa, resultset, cascade

I´m learning JPA and waned to create a new entry on my table with JPA, cascading the child elements.

The code works fine until I want to persist a new entry. I initially thought it was a mapping error but I didnt find anything wrong in my database structure (or I´m hallucinating bc of the heat)

So why cant I persist?

**Client**

```
package client;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import dao.GeneralDAO;
import entity.Artemis;
import entity.Welt;

public class client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GeneralDAO artemis = new GeneralDAO("JPA_REAL", Artemis.class);
        System.out.println(artemis);
        GeneralDAO welt = new GeneralDAO("JPA_REAL", Welt.class);
        System.out.println(welt);

        System.out.println("Artemis Liste: " + artemis.list());
        System.out.println("Artems by PK: " + artemis.findByPrimaryKey(1));
        System.out.println("Welt by PK: " + welt.findByPrimaryKey(2));
        System.out.println("Welt Liste: " + welt.list());

        Collection<?> objs;
        Collection<?> objs1;

        objs = artemis.list();
        objs1 = welt.list();

        Artemis art1 = null;

        System.out.println("Field: " + artemis.getField());


  Artemis a2 = new Artemis("Zeus");

          Artemis a3 = new Artemis();

          a3.setName("Jupiter");

          List<Welt> a2_welt = new ArrayList<Welt>();

          a2_welt.add(new Welt("Earth"));

          a2_welt.add(new Welt("Mars"));

          a2.setWelts(a2_welt);

          artemis.store(a2);





        for (Object s : objs) {
            System.out.println("s=" + ((Artemis) s).getName());
            System.out.println("id=" + ((Artemis) s).getId());
            for (Welt w : ((Artemis) s).getWelts())
                System.out.println("w=" + w.getName());
        }

        artemis.close();
        welt.close();
    }
}
```

**DAO**

```
package dao;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.*;



public class GeneralDAO {

    EntityManager em;
    private Field[] field;
    private int primaryKeyIndex;



    private Class <?> clazz;

    public GeneralDAO(String PersistenceUnit, Class <?> clazz) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnit);
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    this.clazz=clazz;   
    }


    public Field[] getField() {
        field = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

        return field;
    }

    public Collection <?> list(){
        String Statement = "Select q from " + clazz.getSimpleName() + " q";
        return em.createQuery(Statement).getResultList();
    }

    public Object findByPrimaryKey(int pk) {
        Object returnObject = em.find(clazz, pk);
        return returnObject;
    }

    public void store(Object s) {
        EntityTransaction ta = em.getTransaction();
        ta.begin();
        em.persist(s);
        ta.commit();

    }

    public void remove(int pk) {
        Object returnObject = em.find(clazz, pk);
        EntityTransaction ta = em.getTransaction();
        ta.begin();
        em.remove(returnObject);
        ta.commit();
    }

    public void close() {
        em.clear();
        em.close();


    }

    public void refresh(Object s) {
        em.refresh(s);
    }
    /*
     * public Collection <?> executeQuery() { System.out.println("Query Start");
     * Query Query = em.createQuery("Select e from Artemis e join e.id t");
     * List<Artemis> resultList = Query.getResultList(); for (Artemis s: resultList)
     * System.out.println(Artemis.getName() "+" Artemis.getWorld()); }
     */

}
```

**Welt Entity**

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the WELT database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Welt.findAll", query="SELECT w FROM Welt w")
public class Welt implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Artemis
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_artemis")
    private Artemis artemis;

    public Welt() {

    }

    public Welt(int i, String string, int j) {

    }

    public Welt(int i, String string) {
    }

    public Welt(String string) {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Artemis getArtemis() {
        return this.artemis;
    }

    public void setArtemis(Artemis artemis) {
        this.artemis = artemis;
    }

}
```

**Artemis Entity**

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * The persistent class for the ARTEMIS database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Artemis.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Artemis a")
public class Artemis implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Welt
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="artemis", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Welt> welts = new ArrayList<Welt>();

    public Artemis() {
    }

    public Artemis(int id, String name) {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
    }

    public Artemis(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Welt> getWelts() {
        return welts;
    }

    public Collection<Welt> getWeltName() {
        return welts;
    }

    public void setWelts(List<Welt> welts) {
        this.welts = welts;
    }

    public Welt addWelt(Welt welt) {
        getWelts().add(welt);
        welt.setArtemis(this);

        return welt;
    }

    public Welt removeWelt(Welt welt) {
        getWelts().remove(welt);
        welt.setArtemis(null);

        return welt;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Artemis [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", welts=" + welts + "]";
    }


}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
//other console output
    dao.GeneralDAO@77c1e611
    Artemis Liste: []
    Artems by PK: null
    Welt by PK: null
    Welt Liste: []
    Field: [Ljava.lang.reflect.Field;@17fede14
    Juni 27, 2019 9:06:16 NACHM. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
    WARN: SQL Error: 2289, SQLState: 42000
    Juni 27, 2019 9:06:16 NACHM. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
    ERROR: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

    Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
        at dao.GeneralDAO.store(GeneralDAO.java:46)
        at client.client.main(client.java:77)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure$1.getNextValue(SequenceStructure.java:95)
        at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
        at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:519)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:119)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:804)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1052)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:537)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:255)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:610)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:253)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:86)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:765)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:921)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1099)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3640)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1384)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3687)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1165)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
        ... 11 more
    Caused by: Error : 2289, Position : 7, Sql = select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual, OriginalSql = select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual, Error Msg = ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
        ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it failed was my database had no sequence that is used in @Generated Value

> Sidenote: If I would drop @GeneratedValue and make entries with
>   primary keys (1,"Whatever") it would work.

@GeneratedValue uses SEQUENCE by standard in Oracle but I didnt generate one. I made two sequences with `create sequence ...` for each table and modified @GeneratedValue with typ, name of the sequence and added @SequenceGenerator.

I had to drop a sequence that was in place with `drop sequence dual` and the automatic generation of keys, persisting and foreign keys worked.

Answer (score 0):

The @JoinColumn annotation specifies the name of the column being used as the foreign key on the targeted entity.

On the Welt class above, the name of the join column is set to "fk_artemis".

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="fk_artemis")
private Artemis artemis;
```

**So, this Error typically comes if the foreign key on the Product table is named something else other than what's given in the class and in this case: "fk_artemis".**

**You'll need to change either the column name on the table or the name you're using in the @JoinColumn so that they match.**

There are more causes for this error. But, mostly it is due to name mismatch.

Comment: The fault was somewhere else, and the foreign key entry in Welt had the same name